# Running a single test in grpc

Tags: grpc

How to run a single gRPC test case in c language? Eg: `bins/dbg/server_chttp2_test`

As per documentation, `tools/run_tests/run_tests.py -l c -c dbg` runs complete test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `-r` flag, which specifies that only tests matching a specific regular expression should be run. In the simplest case, you can pass an entire test name to run just that test. So, the command you would use is

```
tools/run_tests/run_tests.py -l c -c dbg -r server_chttp2_test
```